# almost everywhere convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis

I was given this exercise as a homework assignment, and I couldn't solve it, any help would be appreciated-

Define $$
f_n(x)
 = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^k(x-x_k)}
$$
for some sequence $x_n$. Show that $f_n(x)$ is a.e convergent in $\mathbb{R}$, as $n\to\infty$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You likely mean
$$
f_n(x)
 = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^k(x-x_k)}?
$$

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I'll fix that

Comment: Bad x's, $x=x_k$ or x is a limit of a subsequence of ${x_k}$.  These sets are countable.  You need to show that using $\frac{1}{2^k} $, at all other points the series converges.

Comment: @herbsteinberg What if $\{ x_n \}$ enumerates the rational numbers? Wouldn't every irrational number have a subsequence converging to it? Are the sequences perhaps defined to be convergent?

Comment: @Trevor Norton - your comment is valid.  Proving the original question seems to be harder than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** One of those standard little tricks shows that given $a$, you have $$\sum_k\frac1{2^{k/2}|x-x_k|^{1/2}}<\infty$$for almost every $x\in [a,a+1]$.

**Solution:** (If you want to figure it out yourself then don't hover the mouse over the yellow box...)

> You can verify  that $\int_a^{a+1}|x-x_k|^{-1/2}\,dx\le c$ by calculus. So $$\int_a^{a+1}\sum 2^{-k/2}|x-x_k|^{-1/2}\,dx=\sum 2^{-k/2}\int_a^{a+1}|x-x_k|^{-1/2}\,dx<\infty,$$ hence $\sum 2^{-k/2}|x-x_k|^{-1/2}<\infty$ almost everywhere on $[a,a+1]$, hence almost everywhere on $\mathbb R$. But $\sum|\alpha_k|<\infty$ implies $\sum|\alpha_k|^2<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you!! Very helpfull

Comment: So you got it, great. It's a curious thing. Say $a_j>0$. Then convergence of $\sum a_j$ is a much stronger condition than convergence of $\sum a_j^2$: curious that here we show $\sum a_j^2$ converges by showing that $\sum a_j$ does.

Comment: Yes, that's really surprising. I wonder if there is a straightforward proof for this casa

Comment: @NoamPirani Perhaps more straightforward, less of a "trick". also less fun: Let $E_k=\{x:2^{-k}|x-x_k|^{-1}>2^{-k/2}\}$. Then $\sum m(E_k)<\infty$, hence almost every $x$ lies in only finitely many $E_k$.

Comment: Nice! You deduce that a.e x is only in finitley many $E_k$ by borel-cantelly, right?

Comment: Right. By the trivial direction: $\int\sum\chi_{E_n}<\infty$, so $\sum\chi_{E_n}<\infty$ almost everywhere.